# How do I get the data from url use $_GET in MVC?

Tags: php, .htaccess

On my web, I want to add a feature to filter data. I want to send data from the form to the process file using get method. But I can't get the data from url because I already used the .htaccess file. So, how do I get the data from the url that I sent before?

file .htaccess

```sh
    Options -Multiviews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

manage url file

```php
    <?php

    class App{
        private $controller = 'HOME';
        private $method = 'index';
        private $parameter = [];


    public function __construct(){
        $url = $this->parseURL();


        if (isset($url[0])) {
            if (!file_exists('app/controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php')) {
                $this->controller = 'Notfound';
            }else {
                $this->controller = $url[0];
            }

            unset($url[0]);
        }

        require_once 'app/controllers/' . $this->controller . '.php';
        $this->controller = new $this->controller;


        if (isset($url[1])) {           
            if (method_exists($this->controller, $url[1])) {
                $this->method = $url[1];
            }

            unset($url[1]);
        }


        if (!empty($url)) {
            $this->parameter = array_values($url);
        }


        call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->parameter);
    }

    public function parseURL(){
        if (isset($_GET['url'])) { 
            $url = $_GET['url'];
            $url = rtrim($url, '/');
            $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
            $url = explode('/', $url);
            return $url;
        }
    }
}
```

index file

```
<?php

if (!session_id()) session_start();

require_once 'app/init.php';

$app = new App;

?>
```

init file

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once 'core/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

form file

```
// BASEURL is http://localhost/website/lapor
    <form action="<?= BASEURL ?>/dashboard/data-aduan/filter" method="GET" class="filter">
        <div>
            <span>Image</span>
            <select name="img">
                <option value="all">ALL</option>
                <option value="1">With Image</option>
                <option value="0">Without Image</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>STATUS</span>
            <select name="status">
                <option value="all">ALL</option>
                <option value="0">Proccess</option>
                <option value="1">Done</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>SORT</span>
            <select name="sort">
                <option value="dateDESC">Latest</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>SHOW</span>
            <select name="show">
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="filter"></button>
    </form>
```

I want to retrieve data from url, but can't.
This is what I get when I var_dump ($ _ GET).

[image: Can't get data from url (The var_dump($_GET) value is just url)]

Comment: How does your url look like? (give an example)

Comment: like this: localhost/lapor/dashboard/data/filter, then I send the data using the get method
 and it looks like this localhost/lapor/dashboard/data/filter?img=all&status=1. I want to get img value but when i var_dump($_GET), there is no such thing as img or status, just url (because the .htaccess file maybe?)

Comment: How does the index.php look like?

Comment: <?php

if (!session_id()) session_start();

require_once 'app/init.php';

$app = new App;

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `$_SERVER` - variable and `parse_url()` for this:

> 'REQUEST_URI' The URI which was given in order to access this page;
>   for instance, '/index.html'.

**In your app-class:**

```
public function parseURL(){

    $pu = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $query = $pu['query'];
    $query_items = explode('&', $query);

    ....
```

`$query_items` would be an array looking like this:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string 'img=1' (length=5)
  1 => string 'status=0' (length=8)
  2 => string 'sort=dateDESC' (length=13)
  3 => string 'show=10' (length=7)
  4 => string 'filter=' (length=7)
```

If you want to simulate the `$_GET` based on above you could do like this:

```
$get = array();
foreach($query_items as $key => $qi) {
    $r = explode('=', $qi);
    $get[$r[0]] = $r[1];
}
```

and the result of `$get` would be:

```
array (size=5)
  'img' => string '1' (length=1)
  'status' => string '0' (length=1)
  'sort' => string 'dateDESC' (length=8)
  'show' => string '10' (length=2)
  'filter' => string '' (length=0)
```